# Serendipitous discoveries in Mathematics and Computer Science

Tags: mathematics, discoveries, computer-science

I have recently been reading about serendipitous discoveries in science and I found them quite inspiring. Most of those discoveries are in Chemistry. I'm looking for examples of these kinds of discoveries in Mathematics and Computer Science.

Examples of serendipitous discoveries include the discoveries of penicillin, saccharine and superglue.

Poincare's accidental discovery of Chaos Theory qualifies.

I am looking for the element of surprise and accident. A wonderful proof which consists of an extremely enlightened step does not qualify because the person was still searching for a proof. But, if a person was working in area X and suddenly realized that it's a way of solving Y, then that discovery would qualify.

Note : There is a question on this already on the site. My question is different for two reasons. Firstly, I'm not asking for important discoveries. Secondly, I'm not asking for recency either. Any discovery in the history of Mathematics qualifies.

Comment: Does Gauss' Theorm Egregium count? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium

Comment: @PeterDiehr Can you tell me what the serendipity is here ? I don't know enough about differential geometry to follow ... Was it discovered by accident ?

Comment: No, but the result was surprising.  For a surprising application see http://www.wired.com/2014/09/curvature-and-strength-empzeal/

Comment: @PeterDiehr This was informative and you could post an answer if you'd like. But, I'm looking for accidental results, more than surprising or counter-intuitive ones. Nevertheless, I'm glad to have learnt something new.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587155/serendipitous-mathematical-discoveries-in-recent-times

Comment: This 500+ page paper, available to read online for free, given extensive detail of serendipitous discoveries in maths : http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322795?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @NickR Wow, thanks a lot. I haven't looked at the paper yet. I didn't make an account yet. How did you manage to get a free paper from MAA ? Also, how did you know there was a paper like this ?

Comment: I just searched the site for "Serendipity".  I'm not a member, so I haven't had a chance to read more than the sample page provided.

Comment: @NickR I am only given access to pages 562-566. How can I see the rest of the paper ?

Comment: I'm now guessing that is the full article.  In my haste, I wrongly assumed the article was the entire journal.  Reading the linked page more carefully,  the article was take from Vol 90 No 8 of Oct 1983 as pp 562-566.  It states "Page count 5".

Comment: @NickR If you find any more papers, please post it here. Also, do you know of any other places where similarly unexpected results are exposited ?

Comment: Sure, I'll keep it in mind.  You might also try searching the ams.org site.

Comment: @NickR Most articles on that website are not available for free. Do you know about the computer science side of it ?

Comment: This article deals with "inducing serendipity in com sci" : http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/sdumais/creativityandcognition09-fp392-andre.pdf but maybe not so much about past serendipitous results.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two major examples offhand.

For Computer Science, John McCarthy's [original Lisp paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html) was meant to be a foray into using computers to represent knowledge for artificial intelligence. Instead, he ended up accidentally inventing both functional programming and garbage collection.

In mathematics, Eilenberg and Mac Lane were studying algebraic topology, and ended up discovering category theory, which had huge effects, from simplifying Cayley's theorem as the Yoneda lemma, to modelling programming languages, to quantum physics.